# How can I parametrize containerid in google tag manager noscript tag

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, noscript

How can ÷ use a variable for `GTM-XXXXXX`? I am using JSF (xhtml page)

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript>
    <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){
        w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
        var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
        j.async=true;
        j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: Isn't your question essentially "how do I output a variable with (presumably) Java Server Faces" ? I do not understand how this is specific to GTM, or Javascript (or even the noscript tag).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have got things confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual can use a parameter referencing a variable defined in managed bean (GTMId in this case)

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=#{googleTagManagerId}"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','#{googleTagManagerId}');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```